# Radio buttons with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change image on radio button clicked?
I have smiley faces which on click change img.(static img- happy.png, active img- happy_1.png)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejff1j9x/4/

**HTML**:

```
<div id="sites">
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="so" value="stackoverflow" /><label for="so"><img src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/Sad.png" alt="Stack Overflow" /></label>
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="sf" value="serverfault" /><label for="sf"><img src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/okay.png" alt="Server Fault" /></label>
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="su" value="superuser" /><label for="su"><img class="imgs" src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/happy.png" alt="Super User" /></label>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('#sites input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');

$('#sites label').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.input_hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.selected {
    content: url(http://impalz.co/ratingicons/happy_1.png);
}
```

I am able to change one static image with all other image.

Comment: This question has been asked before. Search for html custom radio buttons.

Comment: @Nehil Mistry please check to my answer i thing you wan to this and you can do this only css no need jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi now you can try to this only css  there are no need jquery .

as like this

```css
#sites > label > input{display:none;}
#sites > label {cursor:pointer;}
#sites > label > input + img+img{display:none;}
#sites > label > input:checked +img{display:none;}
#sites > label > input:checked + img+img{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div id="sites">
    
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="so" value="stackoverflow" />
    <img src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/Sad.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
   <img src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/Sad_1.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
</label>
        
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="site"  value="serverfault" /> 
    <img src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/okay.png" alt="Server Fault" />
    <img src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/okay_1.png" alt="Server Fault" />
</label>
    
    
            
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="site" value="superuser" />
    <img class="imgs" src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/happy.png" alt="Super User" />
    <img class="imgs" src="http://impalz.co/ratingicons/happy_1.png" alt="Super User" />
</label>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question properly this is what you are trying check below code:

```
$('#sites label').click(function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src","imagepath");
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```